# question about db design

Tags: database-design

I am struggling with the database design for a students / courses administration tool.

Students can book different courses, e.g. course A, B, C...

To complete a course you have to meet some specific requirements like a minimum number of general lessons plus course specific lessons. For each course you have different figures.

> e.g. course A --> min. general lessons 10, course specific lessons 4
>
> e.g. course B --> min. general lessons 10, course specific lessons 2

Now my problem: You can book e.g. A and B together then you will get a credit of one time 'min. general lessons 10, though you have only:

> course AB --> min. general lessons 10, course specific lessons 4 (course A) plus course specific lessons 2 (course B)

Any ideas for a proper table layout?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Edit the title of your question to be a *specific* summary of your issue.

Comment: haven't decided yet i am still in the planning phase but I am considering sqlite

Comment: From what you have written id say that your problem is not a schema issue. I would expect tables for Students, Enrolements, Courses and Attendance should be sufficient. The question of whether a student has passed a course or not should be answered with a report or by the application.